# Repeated Measures MANCOVA possible to do in Python?

Tags: statsmodels, anova, ancova

I want to do a repeated measures MANCOVA in python but have been struggling to find resources/code online. Does anyone have examples of code/packages recommendations for this type of analysis on python?

Thank you!

I have tried the package statsmodels for ANOVA, but cannot find code for MANCOVA.

Comment: Actually, MANOVA in statsmodels is implemented through the multivariate linear model and takes categorical as well as continuous explanatory variables (similar to OLS plus anova_lm for univariate) https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.multivariate.manova.MANOVA.html

Comment: e.g. for one-way https://github.com/marsja/jupyter/blob/master/MANOVA_Test_in_Python_Statsmodels_Example.ipynb or multi-way manova with interaction and Helmert (orthogonal) coding https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/8713

Answer (score 0):

Actually the code for manova and mancova are the same the only different is that in mancova the categorical variables must be two or more and with manova categorical variables is one